Connecting HMI to the web without vpn / DDNS
I have multiple systems deployed on many sites.
each of these systems has an HMI device that runs a VNC server for remote maintenance.
at this moment each of these systems is offline, and each device on the network is using a private IP.
now the clients that are buying these systems from me can provide a network connection,
but not all of them can provide a static IP or Port forwarding.
I thought I could maybe do this with a private VPN server and a PFSense or something similar.
but since all of the HMI devices require the same static IP Address, I think this won't work smoothly as well
is there a solution that I can set up to provide an online connection to these HMIs, and is there a way to keep such a connection secured?

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Simply assign each VPN client a unique (dynamic) IP address on its VPN link - after all, it's another interface requiring another IP address.

I have less experience with VPNs but still there is some thing missing for me. I can't really install a VPN client to the HMI. I can't install any additional software on that device. What I can do is add another router with a VPN client. How can I assign different IP address to a device only using the router ? Is there something I am missing ?

You could add a router with VPN client function to the setup, and use destination/reverse NAT/port forwarding from its VPN address to the HMI address, effectively hiding that address from the central network.
